# google_play_scraper cannot crawl all reviews

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, google-crawlers

AS I followed codes of `reviews_all` from https://github.com/JoMingyu/google-play-scraper
I sitll cannot get all reviews, just only a few and not even sorted by date. Is it because I need to write a loop? or anything I missed?
Thank you!

My code is as shown below:

```
from google_play_scraper import Sort, reviews_all

result = reviews_all(
    'grasea.familife',
    sleep_milliseconds=0, # defaults to 0
    lang='zh', # defaults to 'en'
    country='TW', # defaults to 'us'
    sort=Sort.NEWEST, # defaults to Sort.MOST_RELEVANT
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to scrap using the default too. and also language. i tried to create two dataframes and merge them. because there are reviewers who use google app with a different language and country

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31665194)